# Detect parameters in dbCommand

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that accepts an SQL statement like this:

```
Public ExecuteReader(ByVal strSQL As String)
    Dim objCommand as New SQLCommand(strSQL)
End Public
```

The previous developer concatenated strings like this (prone to SQL injection, I know):

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID = " & intID & "
```

I am now using SQL parameters e.g. `strSQL` could now be

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID = @ID
```

The only option I believe is to have the calling function add the parameters and pass the parameter values to `ExecuteReader` i.e.

```
Public ExecuteReader(ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal params as dbParameter)
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way would be to use

```
addWithValue("@ID", value)
```

I don't think there's an easier way...